# Ubuntu 23.04 flutter installer fails with custom partitioning

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, btrfs, subiquity, xfs

The new Ubuntu installer consistently fails to complete installation when using custom partitioning. It only works when selecting Erase Disk and using the default settings. How do I fix this? I'm trying to install Ubuntu Desktop 23.04 with the new flutter-based installer. I have a NVME SSD. I used Gparted to create a 1GB EFI partition and formatted it as FAT32. Then I started the new Ubuntu installer, selected Manual Partition and created a 465GB XFS partition that used the rest of the disk. Every time I use custom partitioning I get an error saying Installation Failed. It doesn't matter if I use XFS, Btrfs or JFS. If I simply select Erase Disk then Ubuntu installs successfully.

Comment: As stated in my original post I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 23.04. There was previously an update to the new Flutter installer in the Software Center but all it seemed to do is enable ZFS install. It did nothing to fix the installation failure when using custom partitioning with in-kernel filesystems.